# Prove that the number of solutions to $x^2+y^2<N^2$, where $x$, $y$ are integers and $N$ is a fixed natural number, cannot be even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that the number of solutions $(x,y)$ to equation $x^2+y^2<N^2$, where $x$, $y$ are integers and $N$ is a fixed natural number, cannot be even?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: *Hint*: false for $N=0$, otherwise assuming $N$ is fixed and consider rotation in $xy$-plane.

Comment: It may help if you try plotting these for some small value of $N$, like $4$ or $6$.  See what symmetries show up.

Comment: You should make it clear that $N$ is fixed and the "number of solutions" refers to the number of pairs $(x,y)$. Otherwise, there are infinitely many triples $(x,y,N)$ satisfying the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ is such that $x^2+y^2<N$, you can pair it with $(-x,-y)$, which is also a solution. Moreover, $(x,y)=(-x,-y)\iff (x,y)=(0,0)$ therefore there is an even number of solutions that are not $(0,0)$. Adding $(0,0)$ gives you that there is an odd number of solutions.